# Responsive not working properly in map

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, css-position

I have a website http://xi-spain.com/. It is responsive too. But I have got some problems while putting a world map with country links in it. The map looks good at my computer resolution but when i re-size the browser, the links goes besides the country locations. I have put all the links by absolute positioning using percentage values but it is not working responsive properly. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Please post the related code in a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete working example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Take a look at David Bradshaw's [Image Map Resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at reapproaching the way you're looking at executing this.

On smaller screens it doesn't make sense to have the map showing with a bunch of labels, the room just won't be there.

By default, from a mobile first perspective, I would list all of the country/locations in an alphabetical list. Then once the viewport is large enough to allow a world map with labels to appear then load in the map and position the labels.  An example can be seen here http://www.imiplc.com/graduates

Comment: So, i need to list links in mobile right? Alright, Then can i make it responsive at least for tablet or small desktops?